# \visible{} messes up alignment in table

Tags: tables, beamer, alignment

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[t]
        \begin{tabular}{p{0.2\textwidth} p{0.2\textwidth}}
            Some & test\\
            \visible<2->{Some & test\\}
        \end{tabular}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Which produces this output:
[image]
As you can see when using the `\visible`-command from the `beamer` class it messes up the alignment of the lines in the table (The first row in the table is just to prove that the issue comes from using the `\visible`-command). I assume this is because `\visible` somehow introduces some vertical spacing before inserting the actual text.

My overall goal is to get side-by-side-entries being aligned and appearing at once.

Does anyone know how I can fix this problem?

Comment: Why not use `\onslide*` or `\only` instead?

Comment: @Raven Just noticed. Sorry for the misleading comment!

Comment: Interesting `\only` works just fine so that would solve the problem. Any idea why the mess-up happens in the first place?

Comment: Making it worse `\visible<2->{Some} & \visible<2->{text}\\ ` doesn't screw up equally.

Comment: Indeed... Well whatever. I'll accept an answer stating the findings of the comments here as they do what I asked for: Fixing/Circumventing the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `\only` or `\onslide*` instead of `\visible` leads to the desired result:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[t]
        \begin{tabular}{p{0.2\textwidth} p{0.2\textwidth}}
            Some & test\\
            \only<2->{Some & test}\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

As pointed out by [Skillmon in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/448394/visible-messes-up-alignment-in-table?noredirect=1#comment1126565_448394), using `\visible<2->{Some} & \visible<2->{text}\\` does alo work as expected, but the vertical spacing is different:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[t]
        \begin{tabular}{p{0.2\textwidth} p{0.2\textwidth}}
            Some & test\\
            \visible<2->{Some} & \visible<2->{visible}\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \vspace{1cm}

        \begin{tabular}{p{0.2\textwidth} p{0.2\textwidth}}
            Some & test\\
            \only<2->{Some & only}\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \vspace{1cm}

        \begin{tabular}{p{0.2\textwidth} p{0.2\textwidth}}
            Some & test\\
            Some &  no overlay\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for summarizing the comments into an answer!